# How to condence 3 queries with a ManyToMany relation into 1 with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm setting up an advanced search for a jobboard, 
I have 3 queries that work separately but I can't condence them in 1.

In my entity Advert :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Contract", inversedBy="adverts", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $contracts;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Sector", inversedBy="adverts", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $sectors;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Profession", inversedBy="adverts", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $professions;
```

My 3 separate queries :

```
public function findByProfession($profession)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $query->innerJoin('a.professions', 'p');
    $query->addSelect('p');
    $query->andWhere('p.id IN (:id)');
    $query->setParameter('id', $profession);

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}

public function findBySector($sector)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $query->innerJoin('a.sectors', 's');
    $query->addSelect('s');
    $query->andWhere('s.id IN (:id)');
    $query->setParameter('id', $sector);

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}

public function findByContract($contract)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $query->innerJoin('a.contracts', 'c');
    $query->addSelect('c');
    $query->andWhere('c.id IN (:id)');
    $query->setParameter('id', $contract);

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

And what I've tried :

```
public function findBySearchField($data)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');

    $query->innerJoin('a.company', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.isActive = true');
    $query->addSelect('c');
    $query->andWhere('a.isActive = true');
    $query ->orderBy('a.postedAt', 'DESC');

    if (!empty($data->getProfessions())) {
        $query->innerJoin('a.professions', 'pro')
            ->addSelect('pro')
            ->andWhere('pro.id IN (:id)')
            ->setParameter('id', $data->getProfessions());
    }
    if (!empty($data->getSectors())) {
        $query->innerJoin('a.sectors', 'sec')
            ->addSelect('sec')
            ->andWhere('sec.id IN (:id)')
            ->setParameter('id', $data->getSectors());
    }
    if (!empty($data->getContracts())) {
        $query->innerJoin('a.contracts', 'con')
            ->addSelect('con')
            ->andWhere('con.id IN (:id)')
            ->setParameter('id', $data->getContracts());
    }
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult()
    ;
}
```

I don't understand why my queries work separately but not when I condence them.
if someone sees where there is a problem it will really help me !

Comment: `->setParameter('id', $data->getProfessions())`, so: $query object parameter `id` = that of `$data->getProfessions()`. Next: `->setParameter('id', $data->getSectors());`, ah, so the `id` should actually be that of `->getSectors()` instead? Next: `->setParameter('id', $data->getContracts())`, ah, so if we got all 3 in our query, then we just use the `->getContracts()` results. In other words: you've 3 times used the same "parameter key" and have 3 times set its value to something, leaving only the last. Rename them to: `professionIds`, `sectorIds` and `contractIds`. What does that give you?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I changed as you told me, and it works better. But I have another problem, my function does not take into account the `if (!empty(array($data->getSomeField())))`, I am forced to fill all fields for it to work, if I don't fill all the fields my function returns an empty array, would you know why?

Comment: Probably because `->getContracts()` and the others return an instance of `Collection`. Instead of that check do: `if ($data->getContracts()->count() > 0) {...}`.

Comment: All good. Don't know if you do, but this would/should be relatively easy to figure out if your IDE (e.g. [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)) supports [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/). Would allow you to step through the code during execution, step by step, and see all values of everything, including types (e.g. object of type `Collection`) and allow you to execute (evaluate) code against the current state (of where you stopped execution). Really invaluable tool :-)